# Migrate OAuth 2.0 to OAuth 2.1

Tags: account-security, oauth2, spring-framework, api-gateway

I have a old Spring Cloud gateway working with Keyclock server. I don't have Web UI for login because the project is a Rest API. OAuth 2.0 is used with `Grant type` `password`.

I want to migrate to OAuth 2.1 but `Grant type` `password` is deprecated.

Can you advise in my case what would be the best way to migrate the project in order again to have user name and password to issue a token in order to authenticate users and make API requests?

Looking at this guide https://connect2id.com/learn/oauth-2-1 I think `JWT bearer` grant type is a good candidate?

What if I create my own grant type similar to `password` `grant type`?